# How to find $\min_{a \neq 0}\dfrac{a^TXX^Ta}{a^T\bar{X}\bar{X}^Ta}$ if $X$ is a matrix and $a$ a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Suppose that $a$ is a $p \times 1$ fixed vector of real numbers, and that $X$ is a $p\times n$ matrix where $XX^T$ is a symmetric, positive definite matrix. Now, let

$$
\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i
$$

where $X_i$ is the $i$th column of $X$.

I would like to find the following minimum:

$$
\min_{a \neq 0}\dfrac{a^TXX^Ta}{a^T\bar{X}\bar{X}^Ta}
$$

One idea that comes to mind is to apply the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality but it only works for maximums. Does anyone have any ideas how to do the minimization? Thanks.

Comment: your definition of $\overline{X}\overline{X}^T$ is unclear. Is it $\overline{X}\overline{X}^T = v v^T$ for some vector $v$ ?

Comment: Hi sorry $v$ should not be in there. It should be $a$. My definition of $\bar{X}$ is that it is a $p\times 1$ vector containing the row averages of the matrix $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I call $v$ the vector obtained by summing the columns of $X$. Let $P= I - \frac{v v^T}{\|v\|^2}$ be the projection matrix such that $P v = 0$ and $P u =u$ for $\langle u,v \rangle = 0$.

Wlog you can assume $a = v-Pu$ which makes the denominator constant.

Thus, you need to minimize
$$J(u) = (v-Pu)^TXX^T(v-Pu)$$
The gradient is 
$$\nabla J(u) = 2P^T XX^TPu-2P^TXX^Tv$$
and the solution is
$$\nabla J(u) = 0 \implies u = (P^T XX^TP)^{+}P^TXX^Tv$$
where ${}^+$ is the pseudo-inverse

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\a{\gamma}\def\b{\beta}\def\l{\lambda}\def\m{\mu}
\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\B{\Big}\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\B(#1\B)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Use $\e_k$ to denote the standard vector basis for $\bbR{n}$,
$\o\in\bbR{n}$ to denote the all-ones vector, and
$J\in\bbR{n\times n}$ the all-ones matrix.
Use these to extract the $k^{th}$ column of $X$ and thence the $\bar x\bar x^T$ matrix.
$$\eqalign{
\bar x &= \frac{\o}{n}\sum_{k=\o}^n x_k 
 \;=\; \frac{\o}{n}X \sum_{k=\o}^n \e_k 
 \;=\; \frac{X\o}{n} \\
\bar x\bar x^T &= \frac{X \o\o^TX^T}{n^2}
 \;=\; \frac{XJX^T}{n^2} \\
}$$
For typing convenience, define the matrix variables
$$G = XX^T \qquad H = \bar x\bar x^T$$
Now consider the following quadratic forms and their gradients with respect to $a$.
$$\eqalign{
\a &= a^TGa \qiq \grad{\a}{a} = {2Ga} \\
\b &= a^THa \qiq \grad{\b}{a} = {2Ha} \\
}$$
Write the cost function as the ratio of these forms and calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\m &= \b^{-\o}\a \\
\grad{\m}{a} &= \LR{\b^{-1}\grad{\a}{a} - \a\b^{-2}\,\grad{\b}{a}}
 \;=\; 2\b^{-\o}\BR{Ga-\m Ha} \\
}$$
Setting the gradient equal to zero yields a Generalized Eigenvalue Equation
$$\eqalign{
Ga &= \m Ha \\
}$$
However, since $G$ is SPD, it can be inverted to yield a standard Eigenvalue Equation
$$\eqalign{
\LR{G^{-\o}H}a &= \m^{-\o}a \\
Ma &= \l a \\
}$$
Therefore the extrema of $\m$ occur at the eigenvectors of the matrix
$$M = {G^{-\o}H} \;=\; \frac{\o}{n^2}\LR{XX^T}^{-\o}\LR{XJX^T}$$

In particular, $\,\m_{min}=\l_{max}^{-\o}\,$
and occurs when $a$ equals the associated eigenvector.

**NB:** Since $H$ is a rank-$\o$ matrix so is $M$,
therefore $\l_{max}$ is the **only** non-zero eigenvalue.